# Different shades of the same colour in one plot

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I want to plot several functions in one plot and have different shades of the same colour for each of the plots. Doing with different colours is easy

```
a1 = Plot[{x^2}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
   BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(X)"}];
a2 = Plot[2 x^2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Green}, 
   BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(X)"}];
a3 = Plot[3 x^2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, 
   BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(X)"}];
a4 = Plot[4 x^2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Yellow}, 
   BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(X)"}];
a5 = Plot[4 x^2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Pink}, 
   BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(X)"}];
Show[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
```

But how can I get 5 different shades of red for example?

I tried to use

```
r1 = LightRed;
r2 = Red;
r3 = Darker[Red];
a1 = Plot[{x^2}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, r1}, 
   BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(X)"}];
a2 = Plot[2 x^2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, r2}, 
   BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(X)"}];
a3 = Plot[3 x^2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, r3}, 
   BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(X)"}];
Show[a1, a2, a3]
```

which I found in an answer here, but this only gives three choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`Blend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html) `Red` with `White` and `Black`:

```
ClearAll[lightToDark]
lightToDark[n_, c_:Red] := Blend[{{0, White}, {n/2, c}, {n + 3, Black}}, #] & /@ Range[n]

Graphics[Table[{lightToDark[10][[x]], Disk[{x, 0}]}, {x, Range[10]}]]
```

[image]

```
functions = # x^2 & /@ Range[5];
Plot[functions, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> lightToDark[Length@functions], 
 BaseStyle -> {18, Thick, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(X)"}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
col=Table[RGBColor[i, 0, 0], {i, 0.5, 1, .1}]
GraphicsRow[Map[Graphics[{#, Rectangle[]}] &,col]]
```

[image]

or the lighter version

col = Table[RGBColor[1, i, i], {i, 0. , .8, .2}] 
   GraphicsRow[Map[Graphics[{#, Rectangle[]}] &, col]]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this..

```
   color = Take[Darker[Red, #] & /@ Subdivide[30], {1, -10, 5}];
Plot[Evaluate@Table[n x^2, {n, 5}], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> color, 
 BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}]
```

[image]