# Plotting arrays with increasing color intensity in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, color, plot-themes

Suppose I have a few 2-dimensional arrays I want to plot together,

```
ListPlot[{arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4...}]
```

I would like to give each one a different shade of the same color, so as to signify that they correspond to an increasing value of a control parameter. Also suppose they are many, so I cannot specify for each array a RGB color by hand, one by one.
How would you obtain this?

Comment: Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/187848/58370) answer your question?